# How to write past perfect forms of two verbs in one sentence

Tags: past-perfect, syntactic-analysis

> (1) Alex **had** quit his job and started a company before he won the lottery.
>
> (2) Alex **had** quit his job and **had** started a company before he won the lottery.

I want to indicate that the act of quitting the job and starting a company happened before winning the lottery. I think (1) is grammatically correct and conveys the intended meaning. The word "had" before the word "started" in (2) seems unnecessary. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. *Had* is understood as being ellipted before *started*.